# why is my php session in the smartphone can't be destroyed after i close the web browser?

Tags: php, session

I'm a new PHP and jQuery mobile user, and i'm using them to build an smartphone web APP. currently, I'm testing the APP with chrome on the computer and web browser on my sumsang S7526.

I learned, if I learnt correctly, that a PHP session can be auto destroyed if the browser is closed.

I used `session_start()` in my homepage.php and login.php. I expect that after a user logs in and then closes the browser, the session ends. this does work on my chrome. but it does not on my sumsang.

When I log in and then close my browser on my Samsung, and then I reopen the browser, I'm there still logged in. the session id is the one before.

Even I tried to shut my sumsang and power it on again, the session id is still the same. Why is that?

i tried again. it seems that my samsung browser saves the session cookie by default. including phpsessid. i tried to get the browser close event with $(window).close(). but no luck. is it another event.

thank you guys!

Comment: How do you close browser on your smartphone?

Comment: Please pay some respects to your phone manufacturer. Its `Samsung`, not `sumsang`, no matter how good the Galaxy sings

Comment: @zerkms there is a quit/exit button, and i also tried to shut down my samsung. but the cookie is still not destroyed when i power on the samsung again.

Comment: @ Ø Hanky Panky Ø  oops.. sorry  sir. samsung. ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Session" stored not on your phone - whatever its name. 
Its stored on the web-server.

Browser send to the server only id of the session - using different methids. Server identify this id to track this uniq browser "session" and get data from stored session file or another method of session storage.

When you close your browser - server known nothing about it. Ther is some processes on the server - common named GC (garbage collectors) who clean up old expired session files.

Please read [Sessions reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: You should not forget that this session ID is also stored on the client side. Quote of your link to Session reference: "A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.". Depending on browser settings cookies can be destroyed when it closes which will result in losing the session to the server.

Comment: And so what ? Server dod not destroy session data in case of losing cookie or whatever browser closes or so on.

Comment: Losing the session cookie makes the session on the server unusable.

Answer (score 0):

By default PHP stores the session ID in a cookie on the client side. Try to delete ALL cookies (including session cookies).

For more information check [Session configuration options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

Comment: currently i just couldn't find the event that the samsung native browser is closed. so i can

Comment: currently i just can't get the event of the samsung native browser closing, on which i could delete the cookies.

Comment: Before looking for such things, first you should determine if this really is your problem. You can delete cookies manually to do so.

Comment: yes, of course i can manually delete the cookies. so there is the question when i should do this. i plan to delete them on the closing of my web browser.